# Lua getting (x,y) of player in game

Tags: lua, love2d

I want to find the x and y coordinates of my player in real time so I know where to make the next level of my game. I'm currently using LÖVE 2D to run my code. When I try to print out `player.x` and `player.y`, the game runs fine but there is no text output of the coordinates. I've tried to change the position of where the text is located but that doesn't work. Any help is appreciated. Note: I just started Lua today so be blunt, please. :)

```
love.graphics.setDefaultFilter('nearest','nearest')
function love.load()
  room1Image = love.graphics.newImage('room1.png')
  room2Image = love.graphics.newImage('room2.png')
  room3Image = love.graphics.newImage('room3.png')
  room1 = true
  room2 = false
  room3 = false
  player = {}
  player.x = 0
  player.y = 255
  player.speed = 5
  player.image = love.graphics.newImage('player.png')
end

function love.update(dt)
  if love.keyboard.isDown("left") then
    player.x = player.x - 5
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("right") then
    player.x = player.x + 5
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("up") then
    player.y = player.y - 5
  end
  if love.keyboard.isDown("down") then
    player.y = player.y + 5
  end
  if player.y >= 600 and room1 then
    room1 = false
    room2 = true
    player.y = 5
  end
  if player.y <= 0 and room2 then
    room1 = true
    room2 = false
    player.y = 600
  end
  if player.y >= 600 and room2 then
    room2 = false
    room3 = true
    player.y = 5
  end
  if player.y <= 0 and room3 then
    room2 = true
    room3 = false
    player.y = 600
  end


end

function love.draw()
  --draw background
  if room1 then
    love.graphics.draw(room1Image, room1Image.x, room1Image.y)
  elseif room2 then
    love.graphics.draw(room2Image, room2Image.x, room2Image.y)
  elseif room3 then
    love.graphics.draw(room3Image, room3Image.x, room3Image.y)
  end
  --draw player
  love.graphics.draw(player.image, player.x, player.y, 0, 5)
  end
```

Comment: I don't see any attempts to print coordinates in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output something to the console use `print()`. This will NOT be visible in the game window.

If you want to show some text to the player (in game) call `love.graphics.print` inside `love.draw()`:

```
local x,y = 0, 0 --coordinates at which the text is printed
function love.load()
end

function love.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
  love.graphics.print("This is something I want you to see.", x, y)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate the response :)